# Start chromium-browser minimized using bash

Tags: bash, terminal, chromium, minimize

I want to start `chromium-browser` minimized using `bash` in a terminal.

Currently using `chromium-browser` to open *Chromium*. But how to open it as minimized using a `bash` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/), (on *Debian*-based systems install with `apt install wmctrl`), to send commands to any [NetWM window manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints):

```
chromium-browser && \
last_chrom=$(wmctrl -l | 
             grep -i chrom | tail -1 | 
             while read a b ; do echo $a ; done) ; \
wmctrl -ir $last_chrom -b toggle,hidden
```

How it works:

1. Start the browser.
2. Save the *window identity* number of the most recent invocation of `chromium-browser` in the variable *$last_chrom*.
3. Use `wmctrl` to hide that window.

---

(Optional) To have the window close after running for a minute, add one more line:

```
chromium-browser && \
last_chrom=$(wmctrl -l | 
             grep -i chrom | tail -1 | 
             while read a b ; do echo $a ; done) ; \
wmctrl -ir $last_chrom -b toggle,hidden ; \
{ sleep 1m &&  wmctrl -ic $last_chrom ; } &
```

Comment: This is perfet. Just 1 extra request. I used as `chromium-browser  --new-window website`. Is it possible to close that window after 1min delay?

Comment: Well, this works most of the time as I'm testing, however sometimes it is unable to minimize and close the chromium window.

Comment: @Mr.EU, Re: "*unable to minimize*": this `wmctrl` method works through the *Window Manager*, so any program behavior that would block the WM, (like when one clicks with the mouse to minimize, but it fails -- sometimes caused by a greedy pending upgrade, or some unfixed bug, or critically low system resources), would probably also block `wmctrl`.  Putting a `sleep 5s &&` in-between the `$(` and the *first* `wmctrl` might help, if it's just a delay problem -- if *5 seconds* is too short, try `10s`, or `15s`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying and mentioning _critically low system resources_. I found that normally RAM is almost full when this problem occurs.

Comment: `&&` should be `&` otherwise any code after `chromium-browser &&` won't run until _after_ Chromium is closed.